# How do I stream and queue up songs in a discord bot?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, ytdl

**What I want to do?**

- Search a music by its name
- Stream the music instead of downloading and playing it
- Queue up songs if one song is already playing
- Output to the author "Playing [url]"

**My code:**

```
async def play(ctx, url : str):


    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send("Wait for the current playing music to end or use the 'stop' command")
        return


    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    '''voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name=channel.name)'''
    voice_client = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    
    if voice_client == None:
        await channel.connect()

    
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
```

This code is very basic. It uses yt-dl and works only if you paste a url of the YouTube video.

It downloads the song and plays it which takes time for the bot to play the music

It cannot queue up songs.

It is my first time making a bot and I'm not really experienced in reading and understanding the docs as I'm just getting started in making python projects.

Comment: There's an official example in the dpy docs that tells you how to stream songs from ytdl. https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py#L43 For queues, put the songs in a list and pop the first item off of it.

Comment: [an example of queues](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/ab667b74e9758433b3eb806c53a19f34) written by Eviee from the official server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how here at Rage bots we make our music commands and its very usefull

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from random import choice
import string
from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType
import asyncio
import youtube_dl
import pafy
import datetime
from discord_slash import cog_ext, SlashContext
x = datetime.datetime.now()
from ult import *
class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.song_queue = {}

        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            self.song_queue[guild.id] = []

    async def check_queue(self, ctx):
        if len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]) > 0:
            ctx.voice_client.stop()
            await self.play_song(ctx, self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id][0])
            self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id].pop(0)

    async def search_song(self, amount, song, get_url=False):
        info = await self.bot.loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({"format" : "bestaudio", "quiet" : True}).extract_info(f"ytsearch{amount}:{song}", download=False, ie_key="YoutubeSearch"))
        if len(info["entries"]) == 0: return None

        return [entry["webpage_url"] for entry in info["entries"]] if get_url else info

    async def play_song(self, ctx, song):
        url = pafy.new(song).getbestaudio().url
        ctx.voice_client.play(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url)), after=lambda error: self.bot.loop.create_task(self.check_queue(ctx)))
        ctx.voice_client.source.volume = 0.5


    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            ctx.voice_client.pause()
            await ctx.send("*Paused -* ⏸️")

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            ctx.voice_client.resume()
            await ctx.send("*Resuming -* ▶️")
    @commands.command()
    @commands.is_owner()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def oskip(self, ctx):
                commandd = "oskip"
                print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
                print(x)
                print(" ")
                await ctx.send("skipping")
                ctx.voice_client.stop()
                await self.check_queue(ctx)
    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            commandd = "join"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            if ctx.author.voice is None:
                return await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel, please connect to the channel you want the bot to join.")

            if ctx.voice_client is not None:
                await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

            await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()

    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            commandd = "leave"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            if ctx.voice_client is not None:
                return await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

            await ctx.send("I am not connected to a voice channel.")

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, song=None):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            commandd = "play"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            if song is None:
                return await ctx.send("You must include a song to play.")

            if ctx.voice_client is None:
                return await ctx.send("I must be in a voice channel to play a song.")

            # handle song where song isn't url
            if not ("youtube.com/watch?" in song or "https://youtu.be/" in song):
                await ctx.send("Searching for song, this may take a few seconds.")

                result = await self.search_song(1, song, get_url=True)

                if result is None:
                    return await ctx.send("Sorry, I could not find the given song, try using my search command.")

                song = result[0]

            if ctx.voice_client.source is not None:
                queue_len = len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id])

                if queue_len < 10:
                    self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id].append(song)
                    return await ctx.send(f"I am currently playing a song, this song has been added to the queue at position: {queue_len+1}.")

                else:
                    return await ctx.send("Sorry, I can only queue up to 10 songs, please wait for the current song to finish.")

            await self.play_song(ctx, song)
            await ctx.send(f"Now playing: {song}")
    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def search(self, ctx, *, song=None):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            commandd = "search"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            if song is None: return await ctx.send("You forgot to include a song to search for.")

            await ctx.send("Searching for song, this may take a few seconds.")

            info = await self.search_song(5, song)

            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Results for '{song}':", description="*You can use these URL's to play an exact song if the one you want isn't the first result.*\n", colour=discord.Color.green())

            amount = 0
            for entry in info["entries"]:
                embed.description += f"[{entry['title']}]({entry['webpage_url']})\n"
                amount += 1

            embed.set_footer(text=f"Displaying the first {amount} results.")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def queue(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else: # display the current guilds queue
            commandd = "queue"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            if len(self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]) == 0:
                return await ctx.send("There are currently no songs in the queue.")

            embed = discord.Embed(title="Song Queue", description="", colour=discord.Color.green().dark_gold())
            i = 1
            for url in self.song_queue[ctx.guild.id]:
                embed.description += f"{i}) {url}\n"

                i += 1

            embed.set_footer(text="Thanks for using me!")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def adskip(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            commandd = "adskip"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            await ctx.send("skipping")
            ctx.voice_client.stop()
            await self.check_queue(ctx)


    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def skip(self, ctx):
        if await get_mute(ctx.author) != 0:
            await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from the bot")
        else:
            commandd = "skip"
            print(f"{ctx.author.name}, {ctx.author.id} used command "+commandd+" used at ")
            print(x)
            print(" ")
            if ctx.voice_client is None:
                return await ctx.send("I am not playing any song.")

            if ctx.author.voice is None:
                return await ctx.send("You are not connected to any voice channel.")

            if ctx.author.voice.channel.id != ctx.voice_client.channel.id:
                return await ctx.send("I am not currently playing any songs for you.")

            poll = discord.Embed(title=f"Vote to Skip Song by - {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}", description="**80% of the voice channel must vote to skip for it to pass.**", colour=discord.Color.blue())
            poll.add_field(name="Skip", value=":white_check_mark:")
            poll.add_field(name="Stay", value=":no_entry_sign:")
            poll.set_footer(text="Voting ends in 15 seconds.")

            poll_msg = await ctx.send(embed=poll) # only returns temporary message, we need to get the cached message to get the reactions
            poll_id = poll_msg.id

            await poll_msg.add_reaction(u"\u2705") # yes
            await poll_msg.add_reaction(u"\U0001F6AB") # no

            await asyncio.sleep(15) # 15 seconds to vote

            poll_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(poll_id)

            votes = {u"\u2705": 0, u"\U0001F6AB": 0}
            reacted = []

            for reaction in poll_msg.reactions:
                if reaction.emoji in [u"\u2705", u"\U0001F6AB"]:
                    async for user in reaction.users():
                        if user.voice.channel.id == ctx.voice_client.channel.id and user.id not in reacted and not user.bot:
                            votes[reaction.emoji] += 1

                            reacted.append(user.id)

            skip = False

            if votes[u"\u2705"] > 0:
                if votes[u"\U0001F6AB"] == 0 or votes[u"\u2705"] / (votes[u"\u2705"] + votes[u"\U0001F6AB"]) > 0.79: # 80% or higher
                    skip = True
                    embed = discord.Embed(title="Skip Successful", description="***Voting to skip the current song was succesful, skipping now.***", colour=discord.Color.green())

            if not skip:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Skip Failed", description="*Voting to skip the current song has failed.*\n\n**Voting failed, the vote requires at least 80% of the members to skip.**", colour=discord.Color.red())

            embed.set_footer(text="Voting has ended.")

            await poll_msg.clear_reactions()
            await poll_msg.edit(embed=embed)

            if skip:
                ctx.voice_client.stop()
                await self.check_queue(ctx)




def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(music(bot))
```

just make sure to get rid of the blacklist part
this has some fun stuff to that you didnt ask for but might be use full
if you need help setting it up add me on discord
RageWire#0001
-from Rage bot head dev and support team

Comment: Thanks for this code, I'm kinda new to programming so this code and the other two above can help me a lot learning more about these.